# DataTable with CheckBox jsf

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dataTable with a checkbox column. The data from dataTable I load the database. So far everything is going well. I need that in a certain condition appear some checkbox marked, as I do this?

Following the dataTable code:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="valor" 
                        style="width:100%; text-align:center"
                        value="#{beanMensagemXContato.dataModelMsg}"
                        paginator="true" rows="5"  
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                        selection="#{beanMensagemXContato.selectedMensagens}">



                        <f:facet name="header">  
                            Mensagens  
                        </f:facet>  

                        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:5%">

                        </p:column>                     

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Código" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{valor.idtMensagem}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Mensagem" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{valor.nomMensagem}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Descrição" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{valor.desMensagem}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Configurador" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{valor.indConfigurador}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

Until the code below is the list loads correctly, the screen appears only one of the selected records.

```
listaMsgContato = consultaContatoEmail.listarMensagensAssociadas(selectedConsulta.getIdtContato());
        int l=0;
        int tamanho = listaMsgContato.size();
        selectedMensagens = new Mensagem[tamanho];
        for(int i=0; i<listaMsgContato.size(); i++){            
            for(int j=0; j<listaMsg.size();j++){
                System.out.println("Lista Msg Contato: " + listaMsgContato.get(i).getIdtMensagem() + " - Lista Msg: " + listaMsg.get(j).getIdtMensagem());
                if((long)listaMsgContato.get(i).getIdtMensagem()==(long)listaMsg.get(j).getIdtMensagem()){
                    System.out.println("Entrou");
                    //Fazer o selectedMensagens receber os valores.
                    selectedMensagens[l]=listaMsg.get(j);                   
                    l++;    
                }
            }           
        }
```

I think you're missing something in my xhtm.

Comment: post your table and column with checkbox code snippet

Comment: INMO you should add the needed element/s into the `selectedMensagens` , `selectedMensagens` should represent the selected rows... , do that logic on server side (in `@PostConstruct` for example), if a certain element from `dataModelMsg` meet the condition, you should add it to `selectedMensagens`

Comment: Still did not work. While uploading the records listed correctly, at the time the screen is displayed only one of these records is marked.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with primefaces selection column, but...

INMO you should add the needed element/s into the `selectedMensagens` , `selectedMensagens` should represent the selected rows... , do that logic on server side (in `@PostConstruct` for example), if a certain element from `dataModelMsg` meet the condition, you should add it to `selectedMensagens`